# how can I enable Markdown in fossil tickets

Tags: fossil

Fossil docs says that markdown can be used in tickets as well. But I do not manage to turn it on.

https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/tktview/35343257ffd02ba47880 reports a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read a solution in the Fossil-scm mail list but I cannot find the exact email now. However I put my TH1 templates for ticket in the following snippet:

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/ivzhh/GeL9pq

The basic idea is to set `$mutype` to markdown (`x-markdown` or `x-fossil-markdown`). Then add the redering code on line 75~82 in ticket-edit.tcl (the original solution is this [post](https://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/msg27719.html)). The markdown rendering returns two values instead of one (default fossil wiki command). Please check the snippet.

Comment: Thanks. This points into the right direction. could you please also add ticket-new to the snippet?

Comment: Glad someone picked up my mailing list post! I’ll try to see if this can be included in Fossil’s default skin(s).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it work and have created a fossil repository with the three templates I created a repository with the patches on  https://chiselapp.com/user/bwl21/repository/fossil-markdown-patches. The repository holds the files but also has applied the same in the configuration such that you can see how it works.

Thanks to @etc-100g